# can __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__ be stolen ? Are they really secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I just learned Html.AntiForgeryToken() generates **RequestVerificationToken_Lw** to secure pages fro cross site scripting attaks. On request sever verifies using this if request is same. I m just thinking can't these cookies be stolen by hackers and used to show they are correct requisites ?

Please advice, thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use AntiForgeryToken there will be a hidden input generated for you on the page, and asp.net will check it with the cookie or if the cookie is disabled with urls query strings, and it is safe, and this AntiForgeryToken thing is different for every user, can't be stolen